# Проблема на 3-м этапе  загрузки фотографий на стену пользователя

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, vkontakte-api, php

Open api vk.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js?49" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.init({
            apiId: 3012101,
            onlyWidgets: true
        });
        VK.Auth.login(
        null, VK.access.PHOTO | VK.access.FRIENDS);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                // берем его id
                var id = response.session.mid;
                VK.Api.call('wall.getPhotoUploadServer', {}, function (r) {
                    $.post('upload.php', {
                        url: r.response.upload_url
                    }, function (data) {
                        var mas = data.split(';');
                        var photo = mas[1].split('"'); //photo[3]
                        var p = photo[3];
                        var hash1 = mas[2];
                        var serv = mas[0];
                        VK.Api.call('photos.saveWallPhoto', {
                            server: serv,
                            hash: hash1,
                            photo: p
                        }, function (d) {
                            alert(d.src);
                        });

                    });
                }); //photoupload
            }); //getlogin
        }); //dw 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот в этом месте и проблема... говорит undefined. Что делаю не так?

```
VK.Api.call('photos.saveWallPhoto', {
    server: serv,
    hash: hash1,
    photo: p
}, function (d) {
    alert(d.src);
});
```

Вот код upload.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["url"])) {
    $upload_url = $_POST["url"];

    $post_params['photo'] = '@' . '0.png';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //var_dump($result);
    $result = json_decode($result);

    $mess = array(
        server => $result->server,
        photo => $result->photo,
        hash => $result->hash
    );

    echo "$mess[server];$mess[photo];$mess[hash]";
}
?>
```

Comment: просто как гипотеза: клиент заходит и авторизуется с одного IP, а загружать фото ломится сервер из совсем другого гео-места/IP, что вызывает у ВК паранойу и отказ. Что возвращает закоменченный в PHP `//var_dump($result);`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname);
```